# Many to many dimension table Library Database

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I need to find which category of books were the most borrowed. So, I have the following UML diagram.[image: Library UML]

So when making the dimension tables and fact table I've come up up with the following:
[image: Dimension tables and fact table]

But the Auth (dimension)association table doesn't seem right. Is there a mistake and how can I correct it?
Edit: Probably Category and Publisher dimension tables shouldn't be there. They should be attached with book.

Comment: In what way does it 'not seem right'? What's your actual problem here?

Comment: Now I made up the Auth dimension table. But apparently there are some methods such as Bridge table method, Boolean method etc. So, I'm not sure about my dimension table.

Comment: You're asking about five different questions here. But you're not asking any of them clearly. Read the answer below and respond if you wish with a _clearly stated problem_

Comment: I need to make a fact table, from which I can determine which category of book is the most borrowed one. From the above UML, I'm making the dimension tables and fact table. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the dimension table of Auth, which is a many-to-many association relation. I hope this can clear things up.

Comment: Basically follow @RADO advice below, but you will also need a bridge table to model the many to many from `Book` to `Category` (assuming a single book can be in many categories). What tool will you be reporting in? Are you just writing SQL statements? What kind of database?

Comment: @Ali: basically, the reason you have this problem: all fact tables are essentially bridge tables with M2M relations. If you mistake a fact table such as Auth for a dimension, it will appear to you that you have a M2M problem in your star schema. You do not - if Auth is a fact table, all your other tables have 1:M relations. (Category to Book is 1:M too).

Comment: I'll be writing SQL statements too on Oracle Developer. Its like a Data Warehouse. I'm new to this stuff so having confusions. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your dimensional model needs to be redesigned.

Fact table must be "Auth" with the following fields:

- Staff_ID
- Student_ID
- Book_ID
- Issued_Date
- Borrowed_Till

Then you need 4 dimension tables:

- Staff (contains Staff key, Staff attributes, Library attributes)
- Student (Student key, Student attributes)
- Book (Book key, Book attributes, Publisher, Category)
- Calendar (Date key, calendar attributes)
  you might need a second Calendar for Borrowed_Till.

Comment: Shouldn't the fact table consist of dimension table keys? I'm a rookie to this stuff.

Comment: Yes. Staff_ID, Student_ID, Book_ID are all dimension table keys

Comment: @Ali:  Yes, they should be consistent. At the same time, you should not use "natural keys" for connections. Also, your dimension is "Book", not "ISBN", so Book_ID is a better name for this key dimension than "ISBN_Key"

Comment: @RADO having both Issue_Date and Borrow_Date in Calendar would be a problem?